# How to create dropdown menu in bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use bootstrap dropdown menu, but problem is that i cant find how to change menu from list to be active?Any suggestion?

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <?php
    global $easy_translation_manager_plugin;
    $current_lang = $easy_translation_manager_plugin->selectede_lang;
  ?>
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="background-color:transparent;color:white;border-right:white;border-bottom:none;boder-left:none;border-top:none;font-weight:bold;" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo ($current_lang == 'en') ? 'EN' : 'BS'; ?>
  <span class="caret" style="color:red;"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $url=strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?'); ?>?lang=<?php echo ($current_lang == 'en') ? 'bs' : 'en'; ?>"><?php echo ($current_lang == 'en') ? 'BS' : 'EN'; ?></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.dropdown-menu li', function( event ) {

      var $target = $( event.currentTarget );

      $target.closest( 'li.dropdown' )
         .find( 'span' ).text( $target.text() )
            .end()
         .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

      return false;

   });
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e0a1vooc/2/

Comment: its not working... it not change language in dropdown menu again

Comment: you want a option to be selected as a default?

Comment: i want when user choose something from dropdown it display that as selected value...but when i add text in span i get that new value and old value also

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h  thats how looks now...its not changing value